# How does Discord know what I'm listening to on Spotify?

Tags: privacy, spotify, discord

I'm running Discord in Google Chrome browser. Discord is logged in using it's own set of credentials. How does it know what I'm listening to on Spotify? Is this information public? How do I limit what Discord shows about me?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet to investigate this behavior (if it persists) is to use Chrome Developer Tools to check where the application is connecting to. It may be obvious or you may get some hints. Also make sure to check your Spotify account, you could’ve granted Discord access and forgotten about it.

Answer (score 0):

##### How does it know what I'm listening to on Spotify?

In your User Settings, under "Connections," there's likely a connection you've made to your Spotify account. The simplest explanation for this is that, when you build a connection between your Discord account and your Spotify account, you're authorizing Discord to know about your music activity there. From Discord's [privacy policy](https://discord.com/privacy):

> For example, when you link a music streaming account, we may collect information about that account such as the song you are listening to in order to display that information on your profile or as your status (if you have chosen to do so).

I am unfamiliar with the *technical* aspects of how that connection works, but as recommended in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1629007/how-does-discord-know-what-im-listening-to-on-spotify#comment2617471_1629007), you could use Chrome's Developer Tools to interrogate the communication between Discord and Spotify to better understand their transactions.

##### Is this information public?

If by "public" you mean "publicly shown on Discord to fellow server members and friends", then by default, yes. If you've created a connection between Discord and Spotify, Discord will automatically enable visibility of your Spotify activity and allow friends to listen in. You can toggle this off explicitly in your user settings.

##### How do I limit what Discord shows about me?

Discord does allow you to turn off visibility of your activity on Spotify, but so long as that connection is intact, Discord will still be *aware* of your Spotify activity, even if it doesn't publicly display it. If that's a concern for you, you should consider removing the Spotify connection from your account. Here's an image that displays where that connection is:

[image: Image of the Connections section of the user settings, with the Spotify connection displayed for my personal settings]

The "Display on profile" option shows/hides the Spotify connection from your list of connections when a user opens up your profile modal. The "Display Spotify as your status" is the one that shows what you're currently listening to.

I've had the activity-display settings turned off for awhile now, and none of my Discord friends are able to see my activity, even if Discord, the service, is still able to see that activity. You could just as easily sever the Spotify connection between your Discord account and Spotify by choosing the "X" in the top-right corner of the Spotify connection panel.